# Vsftpd user authentication

Tags: ldap, centos7, openldap, vsftpd

I've set up a virtual machine running Centos 7 and VSFTPD.

VSFTPD is working great when connecting with local users. It chroots the user into his previously created home in **/ftp/pub/{user_name}** with **"useradd -d"**. I've added TLS encryption which is working great too (disabled here in order to see what was wrong). I've set SElinux context of **/ftp** to **public_content_t** ; **/ftp/pub(/.*)?** to **public_content_rw_t** and set 755 rights on /ftp/pub

Recently, I tried to add LDAP auth to the VSFTPD server by doing this:

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=name_of_my_server --ldapbasedn="dc=item1,dc=item2,dc=item3" --enablemkhomedir --update
```

but it only adds authentication to the server itself (I can ssh to the server with a non-local account), not to the service (vsftp), so I came accross a :

> 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/default/path

What I understand from this error is that it tries to log in in the default home (which obviously doesn't exist) without creating a new one. What I want to do is when a non-local user tries to FTP on my server, it creates him a new home in **/ftp/pub/{user_name}** and chroot him in it.

Here is pam.d/login:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

pam.d/vsftpd :

```
#%PAM-1.0
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth       required     pam_shells.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    include      password-auth
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    include      password-auth
```

vsftpd.conf:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
#Permet aux utilisateurs locaux de RW
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=1026
pasv_min_port=1025
dirmessage_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.

#Partie chroot
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
local_root=/ftp/pub/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list

#logs
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES

listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

# Ajouts
use_localtime=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
ssl_enable=NO
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
```

I'm really stuck on that ldap auth for VSFTPD and couldn't find what I should do on other posts on serverfault. If someone could help me or recommend documentation, it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: SSH login creates successfuly a home for the user in the default path (/home), FTP login neither create it in /home, nor in **/ftp/pub** my goal is to create a home for the user on FTP login in **/ftp/pub**

**EDIT2**: As suggested by mxttie I could use pam_exec, but it would be more "getting around" the problem without really solving it. I would have to create a folder in "/home", then a folder in "/ftp/pub" for each user who would connect in order to solve the two consecutive **500 OOPS** errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pam_exec` module to call a script that performs the necessary commands (i.e. create the home in **/ftp/pub** for non-local users)

- Official `pam_exec` man page: http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html
- See the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Pam_exec&redirect=no) for (another) `pam_exec` example.

Comment: I've read how to use the pam_exec, but wouldn't that mean that everytime a user log in, it creates another home ? Or I would get an error on the second login saying that it already exist .. (?)
I'll try to use pam_exec anyway, I'll mark your answer if it fixes it

Comment: hi @Vex- , pam_exec can execute any script/command you want, so in your script you could check whether the home already exists or not